# Slide and Label Update

Tags: cocoa, macos, label, slider, cocoa-bindings

Is there a way to update a label bind to a slider while the slider is draged?
I bind the label to the slider via 'takeFloatValueFrom:' but it's update the value only when i release the mouse from the slider.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu need to set the NSSlider to continuous. Ther should be a tick box in IB to do that.

Comment: Great. That's it.
My fault to no check it before. Thanks